# Getting the CurrentUserID from Websecurity directly after login (C#/ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, visual-studio-2012

I have this website (C#/ASP.NET) with a form where the user can register for an account (it is the default template of VS11) and after everything is filled in and the user clicks to register, it creates the account and logs in the user (which works great).

After this step I want to get the UserID which he was assigned, but it doesn't work. I've put a breakpoint there to see the values of both "currentuserid" and "WebSecurity.CurrentUserId" but they only have a -1 value. Next step is the user gets redirected to the next page, and on that page these functions work. I thought I would be able to get the UserID as the user has already gotten logged in in the first line of the code I provided here.

So my question is, why doesn't it work here? I am very noobish with this, so I am obviously missing something.

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
int currentuserid = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; // This doesn't work, only returns -1
<here I wish to update other tables but I need the user ID>
Response.Redirect("~/Welcome.cshtml");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use WebSecurity.GetUserId(username)

```
WebSecurity.Login(username, password);
int currentuserid = WebSecurity.GetUserId(username);
Response.Redirect("~/Welcome.cshtml");
```

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.getuserid(v=vs.99)

Comment: It seems that this code relies on the username to get the userid. What if two users have the same name ?

Comment: The link is now dead. Also, what if you dont know the username?

Comment: this is very partial, because the WebSecurity.CurrentUserId is mostly needed elsewhere in the code, i a GetUserMessages or smth like that.
and the only ways to overcome it 1) make a roundtrip to the server.
2) when you use Login, keep the uId (as suggested here) and travel with it to wherever you need.

Answer (score 3):

from mdsn

> When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a cookie that lets ASP.NET know on subsequent requests that the user has been logged in. If persistCookie is false, the token is valid only until the user closes the browser.

So, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId will only be useful on subsequent requests.

You'll have to find another way of getting to that information.

Comment: Is there a common proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please restore WebSecurity  connection .
Add following code in the default controller as:

```
     public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                //restore WebSecurity  connection
                if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

                ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

                return View();
            }
.......
```