# WebSecurity shows CurrentUserId as -1

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, websecurity

I am using WebSecurity in my project, and sometimes it shows the current user id as -1 (but that user actually is Id = 1)

here is the code line

```
Obj.CreatedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
```

Does anyone know why that happens? It is not that WebSecurity.CurrentId doesn't yeild be correct results, but it only did for 2 times. everything is working fine in my code, was just curious why that happened.

here is a snap of my db table records where it is saved as -1

[image: here is a snap of my db table records where it is saved as -1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the CurrentUserID from Websecurity directly after login (C#/ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262170/getting-the-currentuserid-from-websecurity-directly-after-login-c-asp-net)

Comment: The `CurrentUserId` property returns -1 if there is no current user logged in.

Comment: @Kitson88 i see. thanks.

Comment: @Kitson88 not exactly. my question was why -1 id happens. and the question you tagged above asks how to get the id of the logged in user as he is not getting it through websecurity.currentId. that is not my concern. i just wanted to know the reason why -1 appears, and that answer is nowhere mentioned in that question. the context is same but the answer we wanted are different.